# How can I change (specifically "config" just like we can config the text) the 'command' on a button in canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this a situation in which I want to change the command of button using a defined function.
In this below code when I click on "Print Output" button it executes "first_func". And the second button "Change Output" is created to change the function(which is to be executed) of "Print Output" button.
When we click on "Change Output" button the function should change to "second_func()" of "Print Output" button.

We can say that before pressing "Change Output" button, "first_fucn" is executing, but after clicking it "second_func" should execute.

I don't know if you can understand my question or not, but please help me with this problem in any way you can.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import itertools

def first_func():
    canvas.create_text(10,10, text = 'First Function Executes', anchor="nw")

def second_func():
    def executes():
        canvas.create_text(15, 15, text = 'Second Function Executes')
    canvas.itemconfigure(first_button, command =executes)

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = 200, height = 200)
canvas.pack()

first_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Print Output", command=first_func,anchor="nw", font = ("Bookman Old Style", 15, "bold"))
first_button_win = canvas.create_window(100, 60, window =  first_button)


toggle_funcs = itertools.cycle((second_func, first_func))

def toggle():
    func = next(toggle_funcs)
    func()

second_button = tk.Button(canvas, text = "Change Output", command = toggle,anchor="nw", font = ("Bookman Old Style", 15, "bold"))
second_button_win = canvas.create_window(100, 120, window = second_button)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that the `itemconfigure` method requires an item tag or id, but you're passing a button object.

If you're trying to change the `command` attribute of the button then you need to use the `configure` method of the button, not the canvas item.

```
first_button.configure(command=executes)
```